# How to handle Yukawa contractions in calculating SUSY beta functions?

Tags: supersymmetry

I'm reading Chapter 6 of Martin's introduction to SUSY http://arxiv.org/abs/hepph/9709356, which is about RGEs in the MSSM. I tried to convince myself of some of the calculations, and I was particularly stuck with anything that has Yukawas in it. I don't know how to deal with them. Take for example the anomalous dimension formula,
$$\gamma^i_j =\frac{1}{16 \pi^2} [\frac{1}{2} Y^{imn}Y^*_{jmn} - 2 g_a^2 C_a(i)\delta^i_j]$$
where, $g_a$ is a gauge coupling corresponding to a group $a$, and $C_a(i)$ is the Casimir invariant. And $Y^{imn}$ denotes Yukawas.

For example,
$$\gamma^{H_u}_{H_u} =\frac{1}{16 \pi^2} [3 Y^*_t Y_t - \dots]$$
$$\gamma^{\bar{d}_3}_{\bar{d}_3} =\frac{1}{16 \pi^2} [2 Y^*_b Y_b - \dots]$$
$$\gamma^{\bar{Q}_3}_{\bar{Q}_3} =\frac{1}{16 \pi^2} [Y^*_t Y_t + Y^*_b Y_b - \dots]$$

the dots are for the second term which I know how to calculate. But I don't know how the results for the Yukawas were obtained!

My understanding is that the indices $i,j,k$ are family indices for chiral superfields. Explicitly, $$ Y^{ijk} = Y^{\Phi_i \Phi_j \Phi_k}$$
So if I wanted to calculate, the Yukawa part of $\gamma^{H_u}_{H_u}$, I would try:
$$Y^{H_u mn}Y^*_{H_u mn} = Y^{H_u \bar{u}_m Q_n}Y^*_{H_u \bar{u}_m Q_n} + Y^{H_u Q_m \bar{u}_n}Y^*_{H_u Q_m \bar{u}_n} + \text{other permutations in superfields?}  $$
If I chose third family approximation like in Martin's notes, then $m=n=3$
But I'm not sure this is correct or where it leads.

Could someone help me with this. How should I handle $Y^{imn}Y^*_{jmn}$ to get those results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three indices in $Y^{imn}$ go over all chiral superfields in the theory. In all the formulae, the factor $1/(16\pi^2)$ is copied from the master formula for $\gamma^i_j$. The factor $1/2$ in front of $Y^{imn} Y^*_{jmn}$ always cancels against the fact that there are two terms with $m,n$ interchanged – assuming that the indices $i,j$ represent an electroweak doublet, not singlet. It's because $m,n$ must be a doublet and singlet respectively, and they're therefore effectively distinguishable.

The factor $3$ in front of $Y^*_t Y_t$ appears because $m,n$ go over the doublet, singlet top quark chiral superfields but these superfields also have an extra 3-valued color index so the term is tripled. The factor $2$ in front of $Y^*_b Y_b$ is there because the remaining indices $m,n$ are chiral superfields that are electroweak doublets and there are two equal contributions $up/down$ and $down/up$ to get a singlet out of them. In the last expression for the $Q_3$ anomalous Yukawa dimensions, the factors are $1$ because the remaining indices refer to electroweak doublet+singlet fields but the up/down index for the doublet has to coincide with the same index of $Q_3$ on the left hand side; and because only the quark singlet field among $m,n$ carries a color but it's bound to be the same as the color of $Q_3$ from the left hand side, too. So there is no multiplicity of terms to sum.

Various other terms that could have contributed have been neglected for various reasons and decisions.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dr Motl, now I managed to go through all one-loop and some two-loop calculations :) All the best Sir.